Left mouse click is registered only intermittently 22.04.4
I'm suffering the same issue on two laptops both of which are running 22.04.4; left mouse clicks are frequently being ignored.  I'm almost sure this has only started happening in the past week or two.  Right and middle clicks don't seem to have any issues.  In both instances the mice are wireless but different brands: Logitech and Microsoft.
I've run xev and it's showing that lots of left mouse clicks are being ignored. Two computers, two mice, same OS.
While searching for a solution to this I came across this post: How to fix mouse issues and clicking action in ubuntu 24.04 Noble.  The author appears to be experiencing similar behaviour on Noble.  I'm wondering if some common component or configuration that's recently been updated on 24.04.4 might be at the root of this?

Since you've tried xev it's probably hardware.  I too have had problems with mouse clicks.  In my case, the mice are wired.  More common is that problem with the left button.  It's likely a hardware problem.  My solutions have been to either 1) get a different mouse or 2) fix the mouse.
Option 2 requires having one or more old mice available so, first failure will probably be replacement (saving the defective one for future use). Most of my mice have micro switches under what people think of as the button.  Using a soldering gun/iron or whatever, a needle-nose pliers, solder and some solder wicking - replace the offending micro switch with one from another mouse - remember it was only the left micro switch that quit. Once inside the mouse left and right micro switches are usually identical.

You're right!  Who would have guessed it; both my wireless mice had issues with their left button within days of each other.  A 3rd mouse works fine with both.
